# How to extract preceding strings in a given directory

Tags: c#

The folder names are variable but I have this constant value in the directory - the "distributions" folder.

How can I extract the all the strings before the "distributions" folder?

```
> /<root>/win/<usr>/distributions/<dbms>/<repository>/<port
> type>/<remote system>/<port>
```

Currently I'm doing it in lengthy way (e.g. getting the length of the whole directory, finding the location of distributions word in the string, etc...).

I'm looking for a more elegant way. Could this be done using Regex, or a shorter version of my current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.Split followed by TakeWhile can help you

```
var resultArray = str.Split(new []{@"/"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                  .TakeWhile(x=>!x.Equals("distributions"));
```

Output

```
<root> 
win 
<usr>
```

**Update based on Commments**

If you need entire path based before "distributions", You can use

```
var result = str.Split(new []{@"distributions"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                .First();
```

Output

```
/<root>/win/<usr>/
```

Comment: so should I access the [0] index in this case right?

Comment: result is an array comprising of all the values before "distributions". So depending on which among them you require, you would need to choose the index. If you need all the values before "distributions", you can use the entire array

Comment: ok so if I want to merge the result, I would need to loop into the array and concat the strings as one value

Comment: while merging what would be your delimiter ?

Comment: Do you mean you need the entire path ? or do you need all folder names separately ?

Comment: my delimiter would be "/". I just need all the string before "distributions". so output would look like: /<root>/win/<usr>/.

Is there a shorter way to concat the result? I'm planning the usual loop and concat.

Comment: @ I have updated the answer now. You don't need to get the array. You need to take the first. Please check the updated answer

Comment: thank you very much for the solution (and your patience). it's unfortunate I could only give one upvote :)

Comment: @yonan2236 Glad to help you,

Answer (score 0):

string.split('/') will put each "component" of the path (or any string) in an array splitting them by delimiter (/ here). you could then loop through it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you do want to get the path up until that point i would recommend using regex here is how i would do it.

```
   Regex regex = new Regex(@".+?(?=distributions)");
   Debug.WriteLine(regex.Match("/<root>/win/<usr>/distributions/<dbms>/<repository>").Value);
```

this outputs 
     `/<root>/win/<usr>/`

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem with the good old way?

```
var s = "/<root>/win/<usr>/distributions/<dbms>/<repository>/<port.....";
var result = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("distributions"));
```

or `s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("/distributions/")+1)` if that text might appeare in other form too...

Comment: more expensive then looping through the string twice?

Comment: And allocating an array. But feel free to run a benchmark. Anyway, splitting a string by a long text and not by just some separators is anything but clean IMHO - although it certainly works, it is quite far from what split was intended for.